# How bad an idea would it be to grant an additional action on a crit?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, critical-hit

As an alternative to the standard crit mechanic, how bad an idea would it be to give the player an additional action after rolling a crit? It's kind of like a stunting mechanic (a la AGE system) but I'm not sure it would work in 5e.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and have a look through the [help centre](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help). At the moment, this question is very opinion-based, so maybe try and reconstruct it so that we can give a more defiinitive answer.

Comment: Asking if a mechanic is balanced, provided you explain the mechanic fully might be a good way to reword this.

Comment: @Ben, potentially this is unclear, but it certainly isn't opinion based. The mechanical effects of granting an additional action on critical hits is something that can be objectively assessed. "How bad an idea" is just a poorly worded version of "what are the consequences of" which would be a perfectly fine question.

Comment: Does the crit still perform the initial attack, and then grant another Action? Does the crit still do extra damage, or is it normal damage, but the potential for more hits/more damage?

Comment: by "action" do you mean a full extra action that can be used to do anything (even unrelated to attacking the particular creature that was critted?

Comment: Have you read through the feats in the PHB?  there is a feat that does that.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Are you referring to Great Weapon Master? I wasn't sure because the OP of this question may have been wondering about granting an extra attack on a crit (like GWM does, as a bonus action), but there's a big difference between that and granting an extra "action."

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme Yes, there is.

Comment: It's very unclear what the proposed mechanic is to be able to offer suggestions about how bad it might be. Can you be more specific with what exactly happens when a critical hit is rolled? See also MivaScott's questions above.

Answer (score 5):

## As I understand this question it reads: Is getting action surge as a crit reward reasonable?

Considering classes that get extra attack, this could mean a whole extra round of attacks. Similarly, monsters that get multiattack could get another round of attacks off. Theoretically, this could result in a chain of crits and attacks.

**This seems far more reasonable (although still strange) if you consider it being like the Haste extra action, where it is limited.**

> That action can be used only to take the Attack (one weapon attack only), Dash, Disengage, Hide, or Use an Object action.

A standard action can have a huge variety of uses. Hit dude & pick a lock, Hit dude and run extra far, etc etc. It makes more sense to keep combat rewards in their context.

Second point:
**Thematically, a crit is a very clear idea.**
You managed to hit something in a vulnerable location and you deal extra damage because of it. Explaining a crit as "I was able to run extra far that turn because I hit a thing really hard." is harder to pass off.

**In my opinion, I'd leave crits as they are: landing an extra effective blow. However, you can definitely describe the extra damage any way you want.**
Nothing prevents you from saying the damage coming from a second flavor attack. A monk crits? While the creature was reeling you manage to land a followup blow.

Comment: As it is, the question needs a bit more work before we can properly answer it. I personally got a different idea from the question - the term "action" may be ambiguous. The OP may mean something as simple as a bonus action, or a free movement action (to a certain degree). Until then, answering the question is likely not as constructive as one might hope.

Comment: @Ben I disagree, this answer perfectly matches the question as written. 'action' is not an ambiguous term. If it isn't want the OP meant he can edit the question but currently there is nothing wrong with this answer and shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: Thanks @linksassin, I certainly took the same understanding of "additional action" as you. 
Getting an extra bonus action would have similar problems, especially considering some spells use bonus actions for triggering damage.

Comment: @EagerToLearn an additional bonus action would actually be worse than a standard action. The rules specifically warn against any ability that grants additional bonus actions as they are not balanced for interactions. Your haste action suggestion is the most sensible (though still bad) option.

Comment: FWIW, the Great Weapon Master Feat does something like that ... not sure if you want to fold that into your answer

Comment: I highly recommend waiting until OP clarifies their question before updating an answer. Rushing to answer or update an answer on an unclear question doesn't necessarily help OP or the community.

Comment: I think the answer is fine, covers all the possible options of the question. And the question is clear enough.